# Display content based on location with Django

Tags: django

How do I display content for users based on the location their in?

For example if I would to display only a blog section for users in Canada and not for users in USA. How would I do that with Django as a best practice?

I have not found something that explains how it works.

Comment: It most likely depends on how you define what content a particular area can use, there are geo libraries around that will allow you to filter based on a location but they all need you to define a location somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IPInfoDB's](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php) api to get location and use it in django view. For example:

```
import requests  # pip install requests

def myview(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')

    if x_forwarded_for:
        ipaddress = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[-1].strip()
    else:
        ipaddress = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')

    ipinfodb_data = requests.get('http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-country/?key=<your_key_from_ipinfodb>&ip={0}'.format(ipaddress))
    country = ipinfodb.text.split(':')[4]
    context = dict()

    if country != 'United States':
       context['blog'] = Blog.objects.all()

    # do other stuff in context
    return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                          context=context)
```

And the template should look like this:

```
{% if blog %} 
{% for b in blog %}
{{ b.title }}: {{ b.author }}
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
<!-- do stuff -->
{% endif %}
```